# In the figure, two circles intersect at $P$ and $Q$...

Tags: circles

In the figure, two circles intersect at $P $ and $Q$. $O$ is the centre of the smaller circle which lies on the circumference of the larger circle and $RO$ is joined and produced to meet $QS$ at $X$. Prove that $RQ=RS$

[image]

My Attempt

$1. \angle QSP=\frac {1}{2} arc QP$

Let $RQ$ intersects the circumference of smaller circle at $A$

$2. \angle AQS=\frac {1}{2} arc APS$.

I don't have any idea to move further. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the property of point R and point S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let K be the center and OKR’ the diameter of the red circle. Suppose that M is the intersecting point of KO and PQ.

[image]

From the fact that OK is the line of centers and PQ is the common chord, we can say that (1) $\angle KMP = \angle KMQ = 90^0$; and (2) PM = PQ. Including the common side MR’, we have $\triangle R’MP \cong \triangle R’MO$. This further means $\alpha = \beta$.

By angles in the same segment, all the green marked angles are equal.

By exterior angle of cyclic quadrilateral, $\phi = \theta$.

Then, $\omega = \phi + \epsilon = \theta + \lambda = \dfrac {1}{2} (\omega + \omega’)$ [Anlge at center = twice angle at circumference.]

∴ $\omega = \omega’$.

Hence, $ROX \bot QS$. Result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Construction: Join OP and OQ

1. chord OP = chord OQ [Radii of circle]
2. arc OP = arc OQ [from statement 1, equal arcs subtended from equal

   ```
                               chords]
   ```
3. <QRX = <SRX  [Equal inscribed angles subtended from equal arcs]
4. <POQ = 2 <PSQ [Relation of inscribed and central angles]
5. <POQ + <QRS = 180 [Sum of opposite angles of cyclic quad is

   ```
                                      supplementary]
   ```
6. 2<PSQ + <QRS = 180 [From statement 4 and 5]

or, <QRS = 180 - 2<PSQ

7. <QRS + <PSQ + <RQS = 180 [Sum of angles of triangle RQS]
8. 180 - 2<PSQ + <PSQ + <RQS = 180 [From statement 6 and 7]
9. <PSQ = <RQS [from statement 7]
10. RQS is isosceles triangle [from statement 9, base angles of isosceles

    ```
                                             triangle is equal]
    ```
11. RQ = RS  [Base sides of isoscels triangle are equal]